# Converting Gulp tasks into Npm's script

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have been using `Gulp` for a while and I just discovered a way to run some of the `Gulp` tasks such as browserify/watchify/less via `package.json's` scripts. For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "npm run watch-js & npm run watch-less & npm run watch-server",
    "watch-js": "watchify app/js/main.js -t -o static/bundle.js -dv",
    "watch-less": "nodemon --watch app/less/*.less --ext less --exec 'npm run build-less'"
}
```

Since `browserify/watchify/less` are native `npm` packages I would like to know how can I reproduce/convert (without writing custom bash/zsh scripts) my other `Gulp` tasks such as `gulp-rev`, `gulp-s3` to work with `npm's scripts`?

Comment: Why not just specify the gulp task in the package.json's scripts object? `"upload": "gulp upload-to-s3"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can already call specific gulpfile tasks from the CLI. Just throw those into your npm scripts.

> Tasks can be executed by running `gulp <task> <othertask>`. Just running
>   `gulp` will execute the task you registered called `default`. If there is
>   no `default` task gulp will error.

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/CLI.md#tasks

Answer (score 0):

Gulp plugins are just streams that can consume streams that contain globs of files.

gulp-s3 is just a wrapper around knox, you just need to find a different wrapper around knox that exposes a cli interface.  Or write your own.